# A question on the minimums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus

For any given $a_{i},\ a_{i}',\ c\in\mathbb{R},a_{i}\le\ a_{i}',\ i=1,2,\ 3$, let
$$
S:=\left\{ \left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:\ x_{i}\in[a_{i},a_{i}'],\ i=1,2,3,\ x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=c\right \}.
$$
Is it true that the functions $$f\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right)=\left|x_{1}\right|^{1/2}+\left|x_{2}\right|^{1/2}+\left|x_{3}\right|^{1/2}
 $$  and $$ g\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right)=\left|x_{1}\right|^{1/4}+\left|x_{2}\right|^{1/4}+\left|x_{3}\right|^{1/4}$$ defined on $ S$
achieve their minimums at the same point(s) in $S$ ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for any helpful answers!

Comment: I think the high level answerers are going to ask you what you have done to tackle this problem.  You could get started by observing that the answer might be different if $a_i$ > 1 and $a_i$ < 1.  You might also take the straightforward approach of looking at the partial derivatives, and thinking about what that means.

Comment: @BettyMock: I can prove the case when $S$ contains no point in which one of $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ is zero, but don't know how to prove for the other case. Can you show for the other case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If x = 0 the biggest |x| can be is 0.  So it is not affecting the minimum.